# Whitelist AWS RDS connection to Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: rds, google-cloud-data-fusion

We have a Google Cloud Data Fusion instance that needs to connect to AWS RDS to pull data from it. The only problem is that we cannot whitelist the port 1433 to the world to make a connection to Google Cloud Data Fusion. How can we make Google Cloud Data Fusion interact with AWS RDS without globally whitelisting the port 1433?

Comment: How is your AWS environment setup. Is RDS running in VPC or not? What about the firewall rules for RDS?

Comment: RDS is running in a VPC but the endpoint is publically available. The only restriction is not to whitelist (in security group) the traffic on the ingress port for RDS globally. We don't get a publically available IP when we spawn Google Cloud Data Fusion and that's why we don't have an IP which can be whitelisted in our security group. Kindly help if you have any information about the process that can be followed, @KunalDeo

Comment: What about VPN? Quick googling: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-ha-vpn-with-aws Connects VPCs and whitelist private subnets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by connection your AWS and GCP project through VPN. for more details refer below link

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/automated-network-deployment-multicloud

Comment: the main problem is that we can't modify the AWS VPC and we wanted to whitelist a public IP (or a range of public IPs) of Cloud Data Fusion in security group attached to the RDS instance.

Comment: in that case you can use RDS proxy and connect  cloud data fusion through RDS proxy

Comment: Then the question comes back on the same page, @divyang4481. We don't want to open the traffic to the public internet, Google Cloud Data Fusion does not provide any public IPs and thus we wouldn't be able to whitelist any IPs for Cloud Data Fusion for RDS proxy access.
Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: there is not way you can find  public IP that use to connect your RDS. you can do through VPN only to have better control.

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-gcp-apis-from-an-external-network